# Reverse relation of foreign keys in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two tables connected via foreign keys.

Models.py

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    A = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    B = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    C = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Bar(models.Model):
    X = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='foo_a')
    Y = models.CharField(default=0)
    Z = models.CharField(default=0)
```

Views.py

```
def foo_details(request):

    query = Foo.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'foodetails.html', {'query': inward})
```

HTML

```
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>Y</th>
        <th>Z</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for i in query %}

           <tr>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.A }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.B }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.C }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.?? }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.?? }}</td>

           </tr>
```

How can I show the related field of Bar model in my template?

If the query in my views was `Bar.objects.all()` then in my templates I could easily do

```
<td class="align-middle">{{ i.X.A }}</td>
```

But how can I use the reverse relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ForeignKey is a *many-to-one* relationship; you have many Bars related to your Foo. You need to iterate through them using the related_name.

```
{% for i in query %}
   <tr>
    <td class="align-middle">{{ i.A }}</td>
    <td class="align-middle">{{ i.B }}</td>
    <td class="align-middle">{{ i.C }}</td>
    {% for bar in i.foo_a.all %}
    <td class="align-middle">{{ bar.Y }}</td>
    <td class="align-middle">{{ bar.Z }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What if I have 3 levels of foreign key relation?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
def foo_details(request,pk):
    foo_obj = Foo.obejcts.get(pk=pk)
    query = Foo.objects.all()
    bar = Bar.objects.filter(x=foo_obj)
```

OR if you want to handle this just within your template you can try like this:

```
{% for i in query %}
         <tr>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.A }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.B }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.C }}</td>
{% for bar in i.foo_a.all %} # if you don't specify related_name it will be i.modelname_set.all
            <td class="align-middle">{{ bar.x }}</td>
{% endfor %}

           </tr> 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply access the reverse relation (for an instance of `Foo`) through `instance.foo_a` (That's what the related_name is for)

In a template, you'd use something like this:

```
{% for obj in instance.foo_a %}
    <td> {{ obj.A }} </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Equivalent to this would be `instance.bar_set.all`